# Array of textview and button in proper layout

Tags: android, arrays, button, textview

I searched a lot regarding this issue. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iouI.png)

As shown in above image I have only created 2 rows but I want to design 20 rows, each having button:01, button:02, textview, button:03. Is there any way to write array of button and textview together in this layout instead of designing 20 textviews and 60 buttons?? 
I know ListView is a good option but I would like to know if there is any other option.

Comment: What you are looking for is [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: so, is it not possible to put array of button and textview together in a proper layout using java code?